# Trying to get data from a datasource to kendo grid using a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have this grid

```
$("#attachmentsGrid2").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "name",
        template: "<strong>#: FileName# </strong>"
    }],
    dataSource: viewModel.get("entity")
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

and this a picture of the viewmodel
[image]

Trying to get the FileName from TemplateFileData for every file inside the grid.

Any idea what am i doing wrong and it doesnt shows it on grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it as simple as:

```
dataSource: viewModel.get("entity.TemplateFilesData")
```

The grid expects as its datasource either a kendo datasource or an array.